# How to get the following resultt in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
{
   "DeviceProfile": {
   "-xmlns": "http://www.hp.com/schema/m2m/",
   "Metadata": {
   "Model": "DEMO",
   "OntologyReference": {
    "-xmlns:tns": "http://www.YY.com/schema/m2m/",
    "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    }
  },
  "AssetParams": [
    {
      "-ParamName": "Device-ID",
      "-DisplayName": "Device-ID",
      "-Mandatory": "true",
      "-ReadOnly": "true",
      "-DataType": "String",
      "-Category": "IoT",
      "-LiveUpdate": "false",
      "-xpath": "'Unit-ID''",
      "-Decoding": "none",
      "-MinLength": "1"
    },
    {
      "-ParamName": "deviceHost",
      "-DisplayName": "Device Host",
      "-Mandatory": "false",
      "-ReadOnly": "false",
      "-DataType": "String",
      "-Category": "IoT",
      "-Decoding": "none"
    }
    ]
    }
    }
```

How to get only AssetParams as json object in javascript like this:

```
{"AssetParams": [
    {
      "-ParamName": "Device-ID",
      "-DisplayName": "Device-ID",
      "-Mandatory": "true",
      ....
      ]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
  "DeviceProfile": {
    "-xmlns": "http://www.hp.com/schema/m2m/",
    "Metadata": {
      "Model": "DEMO",
      "OntologyReference": {
        "-xmlns:tns": "http://www.YY.com/schema/m2m/",
        "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      }
    },
    "AssetParams": [{
        "-ParamName": "Device-ID",
        "-DisplayName": "Device-ID",
        "-Mandatory": "true",
        "-ReadOnly": "true",
        "-DataType": "String",
        "-Category": "IoT",
        "-LiveUpdate": "false",
        "-xpath": "'Unit-ID''",
        "-Decoding": "none",
        "-MinLength": "1"
      },
      {
        "-ParamName": "deviceHost",
        "-DisplayName": "Device Host",
        "-Mandatory": "false",
        "-ReadOnly": "false",
        "-DataType": "String",
        "-Category": "IoT",
        "-Decoding": "none"
      }
    ]
  }
};

let {AssetParams} = obj.DeviceProfile;
let theJsonYouAskedFor = JSON.stringify({AssetParams});
console.log(theJsonYouAskedFor);
```